# How to configure Amazon EC2 instance to support python profiler?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have AWS EC2 instances with stuff running and the python profiler is broken there

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
  cProfile.run("test()")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/cProfile.py", line 36, in run
    result = prof.print_stats(sort)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/cProfile.py", line 80, in print_stats
    import pstats
ImportError: No module named pstats
```

I'd rather not reinstall all of Python because there is stuff running on the systems.
I just want to add/fix the profiler.  I've found advice on how to do this which didn't work, for example http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/ProfilingOnDebian. No matter what I try I get

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-profiler
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-profiler is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package python-profiler has no installation candidate
```

Any help?  To reiterate, I've tried adding various lines to the sources.list file and
nothing has worked, so please don't just search and post a link unless you have solved
this problem successfully yourself, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that the missing module [pstats.py](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/pstats.py) is a plain python module, so all you have to do is put
it somewhere on the Python path.

I'm not deleting this in the hope that it will help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

The Python profiler lives in the community-supported Ubuntu “multiverse” so to install the Python profiler you simply need to uncomment the multiverse lines in your APT sources file. If you are trying to automate a server install — like I am — then these commands should work:

```
$ sudo sed -i '/natty[^ ]* multiverse/s/^# //' /etc/apt/sources.list
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install python-profiler
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can directly download python-profiler package and run dpkg